# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I try return object with Resource and simple Object, but get error:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException:
> Type definition error: [simple type, class
> java.io.BufferedInputStream]; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
> serializer found for class java.io.BufferedInputStream and no
> properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
> disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference
> chain:
> ru.fabit.visor.ui.web.http.model.response.complexes.mobilecomplex.DeviceSummaryResponse["route"]->org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource["inputStream"])

Rest method:

```
@GetMapping(DEVICE_ID_PATH)
    public ResponseEntity<DeviceSummaryResponse> getDeviceSummary(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {

        log.debug("REST request to get summary for complex with id = {}", id);

        var deviceSummary = mobileComplexService.getSummary(id);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(deviceSummaryMapper.toResponse(deviceSummary));
    }
```

response Entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class DeviceSummaryResponse {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Конфигурация устройства", required = true)
    private ConfigResponse config;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "GPX файл с маршрутом устройства", required = true)
    private Resource route;
}
```

How can i return this object?

Answer (score 0):

Your Resource route contains something that is not serialisable, ie java.io.BufferedInputStream.

Try disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS. If that doesn’t work you will need to restructure so as not to reference BufferedInputStream or any other classes that are not Serializable.